# how to make different label with different colour ?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to make different label with different colour ?

It will change all label with red colour.

http://jsfiddle.net/GZaqz/4/

```
     <div data-role="page" id="FirstPage" data-position="fixed" >
            <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <label class="labelClass" id="openSubmenu">Move to Second Page:</label>

        </div>

          <div data-role="content">

<div >
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn" data-corners="false" id="test">Level 5</a>
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Level 5</a>
</div>




<div >
<label class="caseName_h">user name</label>


</div>


<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="">
    <label data-role="none" for="name" class="test1">Phoneyy</label>
    <input style="width: 280px;" data-role="none" type="text" name="basic" value=""  />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
    <label  for="basic">Phone</label>
    <input style="width: 280px;" data-role="none" type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""  />
</div>

</div>

         </div>
```

Comment: Why not just throw in some new class names and control with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Usually JQM use the attribute `data-theme` to assign a color to a form or whatever..
Actually I don't remember if there is same attribute for labels.
you probably want to have a look here: [Theme JQM](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/themes.html) and here: [Content Theme JQM](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/content/content-themes.html)